# Simulated Annealing for the Parallel Assembly Line Balancing Problem

Tags: c#, c++, matlab

```
I'm trying to write the annealing simulation of the problem in the link
```

in matlab or c#, the code I have is as follows, i dont know where is the
false code? cause its not working.

```
 [1]: https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/83055

   clc;
   clear;
   close all;
   MinIstFunction= @Kmin;        
       ---->function Kmin
   for h=1:2
        for i=1:7
              Kmin = Kmin + T(h,i)/C(h);
        end
   end
  end
   %%PARAMETRELER
   T0=100; 
   Tmin= 10^-5; 
   IT=21; 
    R=0.998; 
    p=0.5; 


     x.Position=CreateRandomSolution1(model);
    [x.Cost, x.Sol]=MinIstFunction(x.Position);


   BestSol=x;

   BestCost=zeros(MaxIt,1);

   
   T=T0;
```

```
for it=1:MaxIt
```

for it2=1:MaxIt2
%create neighbor (new permutation)
xnew.Position=CreateNeighbor1(x.Position);
[xnew.Cost, xnew.Sol]=CostFunction(xnew.Position); %get cost and solution of neighbor

```
  if xnew.Cost <= x.Cost
      %xnew is better, so replace the old one by the new one
      x=xnew;
  else
      %xnew is not better, so it is accepted conditionally
      delta = xnew.Cost - x.Cost;
      p = exp(-delta/T);
      
      if rand <= p %if random number is less than the probability 
          x=xnew; %accept the new one (even though it's not good)
      end
      
  end
  
  %update the best solution
  if x.Cost <= BestSol.Cost
      BestSol = x;
  end

end

%reduce the temperature
T=R*T;

%store the best cost
BestCost(it) = BestSol.Cost;

%display iteration information
disp(['Iteration ' num2str(it) ': Best cost = ' num2str(BestCost(it))]);


% Plot Solution
pause(0.1);
figure(1);
PlotSolution(BestSol.Sol,model);
end
```

Comment: Why C++ is tagged? I do not see any C++ code...

Comment: cause i can c++ too. i just wrote by matlab, I added it in case anyone has an idea about it.

Comment: What makes you think your code does not work?

Comment: i think function code is wrong but im not sure.